# Several layers of polyethyleen sheets as a vapor barrier under underlayment & laminate

Tags: laminate-floor, vapor-barrier, underlayment

I am putting 7mm laminate on concrete. I have underlayment (5mm) that requires >0.2mm polyethyleen (PE) sheet as a vapor barrier.

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't get >0.2mm PE but got 0.16mm PE instead.

[image]

My question is whether I could compensate for missing 0.04mm PE by adding another layer of PE sheet, for example using two layers of 0.16mm under the underlayment (or even using much thinner PE that is used for covering floors for painting).

My concern is that there might be a possibility that two PE sheets collect water between each other, but I couldn't find a reliable answer to this concern on the internet.

Comment: Seen old fertiliser bags used as vapour barrier - would not recommend.

Comment: Thickness of PE is usually more for toughness than vapour barrier.  The thicker it is, the harder to punch holes in it.  You need to be more careful with 1.6 than 2.